# Remove tick labels, but retain tick marks in RegionPlot (and related functions)

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, labeling

I would like to remove the numbering on the axes of the following `RegionPlot`. I would like to keep the tick marks but drop the numbering, I haven't figured out how to do this from the documentation.

[image: The inverse image of the interval (a,b) under the metric function d]

Comment: Can you give a code sample that generates that plot?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

An even simpler way that does not require you to figure out the tick positions, is to set the tick font opacity to `0` and the tick font size to `0` to avoid the excess margin where the ticks would have been. Here's an example:

```
RegionPlot[Sin[x y] > 0, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
    FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0]]
```

[image]

Alternately, you could also use `FontColor -> White`, but note that it won't work with all backgrounds.

Comment: I just posted the same thing with FontOpacity, then deleted it when I saw that you had already mentioned it. I would just add FontSize->0 to reduce the blank space in the image margins.

Comment: Thanks, I had `FontSize -> 0` in my test code, but threw it out in the end. I've included it now and made `FontOpacity` the primary suggestion (it certainly is superior to `FontColor`)

Comment: I like this solution the best, as I am using a Show to layer multiple graphics

Answer (score 21):

My preferred solution is playing with `FontColor` or `FontOpacity` as in R.M.`s answer, or define your own ticks as in David's answer.

Another alternative is to change the labels to blank in `FrameTicks`. Since `FrameTicks->Automatic` saves a lot manual effort (and it uses the built-in `FindDivisions` for selecting ticks), sometimes it may be more convenient to transform the automatic frameticks data:

```
 rp = RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2 && x + y < 1, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 FrameTicks -> Automatic]
```

[image: region plot with wick labels]

First extract the frameticks information and change the labels to blank:

```
 newticks = Last@First[AbsoluteOptions[rp, FrameTicks]];
 newticks[[All, All, 2]] = "";
```

Then replot or use`Show` with the new frameticks:

```
 Show[rp, FrameTicks -> newticks]
```

to get:

[image: region plot with no tick labels]

Comment: I think this solution has the potential to be the best, but it leaves space at the top and bottom of the plot.  I propose: `newticks[[All, All, 2]] = Spacer[0];`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, thank you! I thought an advantage of this approach was that one could choose the string length of the label by using a blank string of desired length `"    "`. But using  `Spacer[k]` gives more precise control.

Comment: You're welcome.  I noticed that, rather surprisingly, the ticks change somewhat between your first and second plots.  I added an answer that is a bit of a cheat, but it preserves the default ticks if that is desired.

Comment: When I create my plots I rather specify the `ImageSize` and set `AspectRatio` to `Full` in that way then I can specify my `ImagePadding` to correctly position my plot. I like your answer since it removes the unwanted data instead of just hiding it by making it transparent. The problem I have now is that I cannot extract the ticks marks because it wants the `AspectRatio` to be something other than `Full`. Any ideas how to deal with this?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard In *Mathematica* 10.2.0 the request for `AbsoluteOptions[rp, FrameTicks]` produces error: "Ticks::ticks: "{Automatic,Automatic} is not a valid tick specification."  Odd error.

Comment: @Ghersic That has [already been noted](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/68937/121) in 10.0.2, but thanks for confirmation that the situation has yet to be improved in 10.2.0.

Answer (score 16):

I don't believe this has been mentioned yet:

```
RegionPlot[1 < Abs[x + I y] < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, ImagePadding -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

> [ImagePadding](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ImagePadding.html)
>   is an option for graphics functions that specifies what
>   absolute extra padding should be left for extended objects such as
>   thick lines and annotations such as tick and axis labels.

Comment: Why does this work?

Comment: @Eli well, `ImagePadding` specifies the space around the graph outside of the Frame.  Normally this is calculated to include the ticks and labels.  I tried `0` but that cuts into the frame slightly, so `1` crops everything but the frame.

Comment: It doesn't work when you have graphics outside the `Frame` (precisely because you're using `ImagePadding`). For example, `Graphics[{Thickness[.3], Pink, Circle[]}, ImagePadding -> 1, 
 Frame -> True]` (remove `ImagePadding` to see how it ought to look)

Comment: @R.M correct.  I still like kguler's method because it actually removes the numbers rather than merely hiding them by one means or another.

Answer (score 9):

**FrameTicks**

Consider [FrameTicks](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/FrameTicks.html) in the example below:

```
RegionPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y] > 1/4, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  FrameTicks -> {Table[{k, "", {If[Mod[k, .5] == 0, .02, .01], 0}}, {k, -1, 1, .1}], 
                 Table[{k, "", {If[Mod[k, .5] == 0, .02, .01], 0}}, {k, -1, 1, .2}]}]
```

[image: FrameTicks]

In `Table[{k, "", {If[Mod[k, .5] == 0, .02, .01], 0}}, {k, -1, 1, .1}]` ,

`k` is the location of the tick

`""`  is the label

`If...` determines whether to use a major (.02) or minor (.01) tick on the inside of the respective axis.

`0` indicates that the tick should not appear on the outside of the axis.

Note that the first `Table` sets the horizontal edges of the frame (with ticks every .1 units); the second `Table` sets the vertical edges of the frame (with ticks every .2 units).

Answer (score 6):

You can use the internal, undocumented function `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks `` to do this *(`` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks `` produces unlabeled ticks, while `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` produces labeled ticks)*:

```
RegionPlot[
    Sin[x y]>0,
    {x,-1,1},
    {y,-1,1},
    FrameTicks->{
        {Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity,Identity}], Automatic},
        {Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity,Identity}], Automatic}
    }
]
```

[image]