# How do I place frame ticks without having corresponding numbers?

Tags: plotting, labeling

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove tick labels, but retain tick marks in RegionPlot (and related functions)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2073/remove-tick-labels-but-retain-tick-marks-in-regionplot-and-related-functions)

I need to display a 2D graph, say $y=x^2$ with tick-marks along the $x$ and $y$-axes but with no numbers (*e.g.* 1, 2, 3 ...) indicating these tick-mark values.

What is the most efficient way to perform this task?  Thanks!

Comment: Would you please clarify the intent of this question?  Is this a duplicate?: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2073/121

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For example:

```
Plot[x x, {x, 0, 1}, Ticks -> ({#, #} &@Array[{1/10 #,} &, 10])]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: You sure like your styled plots.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yeah! Don't you?

Comment: Wow, very fancy!  I don't even know what # and &@ do, but it works!

Comment: How did you make your plot stylized like that?

Comment: @QuantumDot [You _should_ know](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11350/193)

Comment: Honestly?  Torn is great but I'd rather you use the actual output of `Plot` not the "hand drawn" version, which I find confusing and already a little tiring.  Are you glad you asked? :^)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Of course I'm glad. Your opinion is most important!

Comment: More Torn?  You'll cause a [paradox](http://gifs.gifbin.com/042009/1241025633_motivational_poster_time_paradox.gif).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard - Singularities are now periodic??? ;-)

Answer (score 8):

This isn't clever, but it works:

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 10}, LabelStyle -> {White}]
```

Is that sufficient?  But, I think the use of FrameTicksStyle in the link in Mr.Wizards answer is better.  Alternatively, specifying your own ticks as MW says gives you more control of tick placement. It's easier to use **`Table`** to specify the ticks, though.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you are asking to preserve the Automatic ticks but remove their labels this is a duplicate of: [Remove tick labels, but retain tick marks in RegionPlot (and related functions)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/2073/121)

If you are asking to place your own ticks without labels you can simply specify an empty string `""` or `Spacer[0]` as the tick label.

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 5}, 
 Ticks -> {{{1, Spacer[0]}, {2, Spacer[0]}, {3, Spacer[0]}},
           {{5, Spacer[0]}, {15, Spacer[0]}, {25, Spacer[0]}}}
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the heads up on the duplicate.