# How can I make hatching filling of plot?

Tags: plotting, filling

How can I make a hatching filling of the plot?

Like this:

[image: hatching filling plot]

I used another plot with shifting to make the filled area above:

```
plot := ListLinePlot[
  Table[{x1[w], x2[w]}, {w, 1.5, 5, .005}],     
  Filling -> Top,
  FillingStyle -> White
  ]

fill := ListLinePlot[
  Table[{x1[w] - 0.01, x2[w] - 0.02}, {w, 1.5, 5, .005}],
  Filling -> Top,
  FillingStyle -> LightGray,
  PlotStyle -> LightGray
  ]

Show[fill, plot]
```

[image: plot]

How can I make hatching filling of the filled-plot?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Something like this?

```
    RegionPlot[y < 1/x && y + 0.3 > 1/(x + 0.3) , {x, 0, 3}, {y, 0, 4}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Frame -> False, Axes -> Automatic, Mesh -> 20,
   MeshFunctions -> {#1 - #2 &}, BoundaryStyle -> None]~Show~
 Plot[1/x, {x, 0, 3}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can add `PlotStyle -> Transparent` to the `RegionPlot` if you don't want the blue filling, and xkcdify it

[image]

Comment: Beware! The anti-xkcdification patrol is here! http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/13359/193

Comment: @belisarius,  oh, but it very much fits the context. I'll defend it as if it was Howgartz against any evil wizard

Comment: +1 for the "evil wizard" ... but your adjectives are too harsh!

Comment: You may always sweeten the answer by throwing in some infix notation.

Comment: One more question.
I get hatches, but I can't combine it with main plot.
I used:
`Show[
  RegionPlot[x1[w] > x2[g] && (x1[w + 0.2]) < (x2[g + 0.2]),
  {w, 1.5, 5}, {g, 1.5, 5},
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0},
  Axes -> Automatic,
  PlotStyle -> Transparent,
  Frame -> False,
  Mesh -> 20,
  BoundaryStyle -> None,
  MeshFunctions -> {#1 - #2 &}
   ],
  ParametricPlot[{x1[w], x2[w]}, {w, 1.5, 5}]
]`
I'd tried ListLinePlot, ParametricPlot and both orders. But it's show only the first plot. Also, I tried another RegionPlot, but I don't think that is good way. Which way is better?

Comment: @shed, it should show both, but that `ParametricPlot` isn't describing the borders of your region. Are you sure that's what you want to plot? Probably there's a scaling issue

Comment: @shed, if you want to plot the borders of that region, I'd go with `ContourPlot[x1[w] == x2[g], {w, 1.5, 5}, {g, 1.5, 5}]`

Comment: @shed you probably should accept this one, or you are still hoping for something different?

Answer (score 1):

**Using `Region` functionality:**

```
Clear["Global`*"];

Show[Plot[1/x
  , {x, 0, 1}
  , PlotStyle -> Black
  , PlotRange -> {0, 7}
  , RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x > 0]
  , AxesLabel -> TraditionalForm /@ {x[t], y[t]}
  , LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Medium]
  ]
 , RegionPlot[y < 1/x && y > 0.8/x - 0.2
  , {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 7}
  , BoundaryStyle -> None
  , PlotStyle -> {Black, HatchFilling[1, 0.1, 12]}
  ]
 ]
```

[image]