# Hatched bars and bar-specific background in BarChart

Tags: graphics, plotting

I would like to diagonally hatch the bars in `BarChart` and to have three different background colors for the different bars, like this:

[image]

Any ideas how to reproduce this image? The closest post I found is [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/how-can-i-make-hatching-filling-of-plot).

Comment: Related: [How do I plot a histogram with hatched shading?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31221)

Comment: @rm-rf The hatching part of this question is a duplicate indeed. The background part, however, is unique to this question. Therefore, I hesitate to vote to close.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries Fair enough. Changed comment to "Related"

Comment: Since v12.1 HatchFilling can be used in BarCharts

Answer (score 15, accepted):

With a bit of manual parameters:

```
barFilled[gap_, h_, seg_][{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] := 
 Module[{width, line, yt, yb, lend},
  {yb, yt} = Sort[{ymin, ymax}];
  width = xmax - xmin;
  line = Table[{{xmin, i}, {xmax, i + width}}, {i, yb, yt - width, h/seg}];
  lend = line[[-1, 1, 2]];
  line = {Line[line],
     Line[Table[{{xmin + i, yb}, {xmax, yb + width - i}}, {i, h/seg, width, h/seg}]], 
     Line[Table[{{xmin, lend + i}, {xmax - (lend + width - yt) - i,yt}}, {i, h/seg, width + h/seg, h/seg}]]};
   {{Opacity[.2], EdgeForm[], Rectangle[{xmin, -h}, {xmax + gap, h}]},
    {CapForm["Butt"], line}, {FaceForm[], Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}]}}]

BarChart[{2, -1, 1.5, -3, 3, 2.5}, BarSpacing -> 2, 
 ChartElementFunction -> barFilled[.65, 3, 35], ChartStyle -> 61, 
 GridLines -> {None, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Like AimForClarity mentioned, to avoid empty strip, we could replace 0 with some dummy value + meta and define barFilled for that value. For example:

```
barFilled[gap_, h_, seg_][{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, _, {None}] :=
 {{Opacity[.2], EdgeForm[], Rectangle[{xmin, -h}, {xmax + gap, h}]}}

BarChart[{2, -1, 0, -2, 1, 2} /. {0 -> (1 -> None)}, BarSpacing -> 2,  ChartElementFunction -> barFilled[.65, 2, 35], 
ChartStyle -> 61, GridLines -> {None, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Comment: Does the grid lines have to be on top of the charts and axes ticks labels?

Comment: @mmal grid lines are behind bars. It's a side effect of setting FaceForm[]. If you don't want that, you can insert one more rectangle before drawing lines. For example, .., {FaceForm[White], Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}]}, {CapForm["Butt"], line}, ...

Comment: @mmal To have grid lines on top of the charts and axes ticks labels one can use `Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}` option.

Comment: Thanks, the halmir's method does exactly what I was thinking about. Using `Frame->True` clips the grid lines to frame region.

Comment: I hav not been able to get around this silly problem, that if one of the elements is 0 in the array, the barFilled function does not seem to be called and so there is an empty strip, any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: @AimForClarity when data is 0, ChartElementFunction seem not to send anything.  What is your expectation when data is 0?

Comment: @halmir, I was expecting that the background would stay the same.

Answer (score 4):

We can use `ChartBaseStyle -> HatchFilling[]` (`HatchFilling` is introduced in version 12.1) to get rectangles with hatched filling. Using the (undocumented) option `"BarStartingValue" -> 0` the horizontal coordinates of bars become successive integers starting with 0 (independent of the `BarSpacing` option value). Then, it becomes an easy task to get the coordinates of the background rectangles using [`Scaled`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Scaled.html) to construct epilog primitives:

```
epilog[col_] := MapIndexed[{Opacity[.2], #, 
     Rectangle[Scaled[{0, -1}, {#2[[1]] - 1, 0}], Scaled[{0, 1}, {#2[[1]], 0}]]} &, 
   col]
```

**Examples:**

```
data = {2, -1, 1.5, -3, 3, 2.5};
colors = ColorData[61] /@ Range[Length @ data];

BarChart[data, 
   ChartBaseStyle -> HatchFilling[], 
   BarSpacing -> 2, 
   ChartStyle -> 61, Axes -> {False, True}, 
   GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, Length @ data}, All},
   "BarStartingValue" -> 0,
   Epilog -> {Line[{{0, 0}, {Length @ data, 0}}],
     epilog[PadRight[colors, Length @ data,colors]]}]
```

[image]

Use `BarSpacing -> 1` to get

[image]

With `data = {2, -1, 0, -3, 3, 2.5};` we get

[image]