# Fill histogram with pattern

Tags: histograms, style, filling

Is there a way to fill a histogram with a pattern such as hatched lines? I'm imagining something along the lines of

```
Histogram[RandomReal[{0, 1}, 100],ChartStyle->HatchedLines]
```

But I'm not able to find anything similar online, but this is quite common practice in my field.

I've seen a few related questions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/49202/hatched-filling-for-listplot) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/filling-a-polygon-with-a-pattern-of-insets) which don't have a natural Mathematica solution so I am guessing there isn't any easy solution.

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34035/hatched-bars-and-bar-specific-background-in-barchart or http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31221/how-do-i-plot-a-histogram-with-hatched-shading? I guess the second is more likely a duplicate :)

Comment: Perfect, thanks!