# Striped bar in a bar chart

Tags: charts

This is my code:

```
BarChart[{{0.25, 0.4, 0.15}, {0.172, 0.25, 0.18}, {0.101, 0.26, 
   0.17}},
 BarSpacing -> {0.15, 1}, PlotTheme -> "Business", 
 ChartLegends -> {Text[Style["BXE", 12]],
   Text[Style["CXE", 12]],
   Text[Style["TQ", 12]]},
 ChartStyle -> "GrayTones", LabelingFunction -> Above, 
 ChartLabels -> {{"Large", "Small", "Overall"}, None}, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 11], 
 PlotLabel -> 
  Style["Volume", FontSize -> 15]]
```

I have to change only the first bar and I want it is like the bar in picture.

[image]

Comment: You need to play with `ChartElementFunction`.

Comment: I should say that this looks awfully like the "chartjunk" Tufte is railing against. Is styling the bar in this way absolutely necessary?

Comment: But I don't know how can I change only one bar and where I have to insert ChartElementFunction. 
I'm sorry, as you can see, I'm not an expert. @Kuba

Comment: @ J. M.♦ Almost necessary, I need to differentiate the first bar from the others, but I can't do it with another color, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: If you only need to distinguish one, make it white (outlined) or black, and the rest the opposite color.

Comment: I tried in white but the difference is not evident and the first bar is already in black, because I have to maintain the grey scale, in order to print it in black and white.

Comment: I know it's not the best choice, but do you know how can I modify the code in order to do the bar as in picture? Thanks

Comment: You only need to do the one bar, not the first set of three bars?

Comment: Exactly, only the first bar in the first set of bars

Comment: How about something like this? https://s24.postimg.org/l8fgtp1dh/Untitled_1.png

Comment: It's not bad, thanks. But there are no ways to evidence the inner of the bars with any pattern?

Comment: That would have to be done through `ChartElementFunction`, which cannot be used on a single bar.

Comment: Yes, That's my problem. Could you please send me the code of the previous?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hatched bars and bar-specific background in BarChart](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34035/hatched-bars-and-bar-specific-background-in-barchart)

Comment: @C.E. Does that answer allow for only of the bars in one of the sets to be changed?

Comment: @Feyre I posted the solution that I had in mind here below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This highlights the first bar. You still need `ChartStyle` for the legend to be correct.

```
data = {{0.25, 0.4, 0.15}, {0.172, 0.25, 0.18}, {0.101, 0.26, 0.17}};
```

Set the three `GrayLevel`s here:

```
levels = GrayLevel /@ {0.9, 0.5, 0.1};
```

Change the `Edgeform` to change the appearance of only the first bar.

```
styles = {{{EdgeForm[{Thick, Black, Dashing[0.05]}], levels[[1]]}, 
    levels[[2]], levels[[3]]}, levels, levels};
```

Plot:

```
BarChart[MapThread[Style, {data, styles}, 2], BarSpacing -> {0.15, 1},
  PlotTheme -> "Business", 
 ChartLegends -> {Text[Style["BXE", 12]], Text[Style["CXE", 12]], 
   Text[Style["TQ", 12]]}, ChartStyle -> levels, 
 LabelingFunction -> Above, 
 ChartLabels -> {{"Large", "Small", "Overall"}, None}, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 11], 
 PlotLabel -> Style["Volume", FontSize -> 15]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

[image]

To create hatched rectangle primitives we can use the function `hatchF` (from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/149307/125) and [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/152558/125) to  closely related questions).

```
ClearAll[hatchF]
hatchF[mf_List: {# &, #2 &}, mesh_List: {50, 50}, style_: GrayLevel[.5], 
 opts : OptionsPattern[]] := ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Mesh -> mesh, 
  MeshFunctions -> mf, MeshStyle -> style, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  opts, Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, Axes -> False]
```

Use `hatchF` to create two `Graphics` objects

```
t1 = hatchF[{# - #2 &}, {30}, White, MeshShading -> {GrayLevel[.8], GrayLevel[.5]}];
t2 = hatchF[{# - #2 &, #2 + # &}, {30}, Directive[Thick, White], 
   MeshShading -> {{GrayLevel[.6], GrayLevel[.8]}}];
```

and take an image from `ExampleData[]`

```
t3 = ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "Metal4"}];
```

We can use `Texture[t1]`, `Texture[t2]`, etc. as directives for styling individual data elements using `Style[element1, Texture[t1]]`, `Style[element2, Texture[t2]]` etc. Together with the built-in (but undocumented) function `` System`BarFunctionDump`TextureBar `` used as the setting for `ChartElementFunction` we get the desired styles for selected data elements.

```
BarChart[{{Style[0.25, Texture@ t1], 0.4, 0.15}, 
  {0.172, Style[0.25, Texture@t3], Style[0.18, Texture@t2]}, {0.101, .26,    0.17}},
 BarSpacing -> {0.15,  1},
 ChartLegends -> {Text[Style["BXE", 12]], Text[Style["CXE", 12]], 
   Text[Style["TQ", 12]]}, ChartStyle -> "GrayTones", 
 LabelingFunction -> Above, 
 ChartLabels -> {{"Large", "Small", "Overall"}, None}, 
 BaseStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 11], 
 PlotLabel -> Style["Volume", FontSize -> 15], 
 ChartElementFunction -> System`BarFunctionDump`TextureBar]
```

gives the picture above.

Answer (score 4):

The question might be considered a duplicate of [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34035/hatched-bars-and-bar-specific-background-in-barchart) question, but for clarity I will show how by adapting the answer given there.

```
barHatched[gap_, h_, seg_][{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] := 
 Module[{width, line, yt, yb, lend}, {yb, yt} = Sort[{ymin, ymax}];
  width = xmax - xmin;
  line = Table[{{xmin, i}, {xmax, i + width}}, {i, yb, yt - width, 
     h/seg}];
  lend = line[[-1, 1, 2]];
  line = {
    Line[line], 
    Line[Table[{{xmin + i, yb}, {xmax, yb + width - i}}, {i, h/seg, 
       width, h/seg}]], 
    Line[Table[{{xmin, lend + i}, {xmax - (lend + width - yt) - i, 
        yt}}, {i, h/seg, width + h/seg, h/seg}]]
    };
  {{Opacity[.2], EdgeForm[], 
    Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax + gap, ymax}]},
   {CapForm["Butt"], line}, {FaceForm[], 
    Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}]}}
  ]

barSolid[{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] := Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}]

mixedBar[args : {{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] := 
 If[xmax < 3, barHatched[0, 5, 35][args], barSolid[args]]

BarChart[
 Transpose[{
   {2, -1, 1.5, -3, 3, 2.5},
   {2, -1, 1.5, -3, 3, 2.5}
   }],
 ChartElementFunction -> {
   mixedBar,
   barSolid
   }
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The idea is to build custom `CharElementFunction`s for the bar appearances. To have variation with a set we need to make a `ChartElementFunction` which depends on the position of the bar. This is what the `mixedBar` function is for.

Comment: The proposed duplicate has a static `CharElementFunction`, what's more, the docs don't show how to do such a dynamic one either. This is a really nice answer.

Comment: @Feyre You're right. I retracted my vote, so it's up to others now to decide whether it should be considered a duplicate or not.