# Texture or shading to avoid requiring color printing

Tags: plotting, graphics, filling

I am producing a graphic that is mostly black lines on a white background but I need to identify some areas of the graph that belong to two phenomena and I currently use a blue and a red shade for those. Because the result would likely be published in a paper-based scientific journal, I would like to have the option to produce a graph that does not require color. I could try using two light `GrayLevel`s (the shaded areas have text on them so for legibility I cannot use dark) but I was wondering if the community has some other proposed solution. Perhaps one area could be dotted and the other lined or something along those notions. I am looking for the code that would produce a dotted or lined surface with ease similar to setting the colors with an `RGBColor` command. I should add that the result should not change as I resize the graph since I use one size for screen resolution and a much larger size for print resolution. So, when I produce the larger image the hatching/shading/doting should also scale analogously.

A simplified example of the code and the graphic would be

```
Graphics[{
  GrayLevel[.8],
  Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {π, 3 π/4}],
  Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {π/8, 3 π/12}],
  GrayLevel[.6],
  Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, π/8}],
  Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {3 π/2, 3.3 π/2}],
  Black,
  Circle[],
  Text["Area 1", {.5, .1}],
  Text["Area 2", {.5, .3}],
  Text["Area 3", {-.5, .2}],
  Text["Area 4", {.15, -.6}]
}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Could you show the code generating the area? Different techniques would apply depending on how you generate your graphics. Have you had a search of this site? Perhaps these could be interesting: [Hatched bars and bar-specific background in BarChart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/34035/27951), [How do I plot a histogram with hatched shading?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/31221/27951), [Filling a polygon with a pattern of insets](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3728/27951).

Comment: @MarcoB thanks for pointing to those examples, I had not found them. I do not understand the code but I think it requires a bar graph, which mine, as you see, is not.

Comment: Also related: "[Generating hatched filling using Region functionality](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64159/280)"

Comment: Note that if you resize the image using `ImageSize` (for the higher resolution), the text will not be resized. So regarding "the result should not change when I resize the graph", it already does – unless you have some other means of resizing it in mind.

Comment: I use ImageSize 6x57 and FontSize 12 for screen and 6x200 and 42 for publishing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It can be done in several ways, but, I am afraid, none of them *with ease similar to setting the colors with an RGBColor command*:)

**1. Using `Show` and `ParametricPlot` with different `Mesh*` settings**

Create four different `ParametricPlot` each with different settings for the `Mesh*` options and use `Show` to put them together:

```
ClearAll[meshedParametricPlot]
meshedParametricPlot = ParametricPlot[#2 {r Cos[t] ,  r Sin[t]} + #, 
    {t, #3[[1]], #3[[2]]}, {r, 0, 1}, 
    MeshFunctions -> #4, Mesh -> {#5}, MeshStyle -> Gray, 
    PlotStyle -> White, BoundaryStyle -> GrayLevel[.8], PlotPoints -> 200] &;

{p1, p2, p3, p4} = meshedParametricPlot @@@ 
    {{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {3 π/4, π}, {# - #2 &, # + #2 &}, 20}, 
     {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {π/8, 3 π/12}, {#3 &}, 15}, 
     {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, π/8}, {#4 &},  20},
     {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {3 π/2, 3.3 π/2}, {#2 &}, 20}};

labels = {Text[Style["Area 1", FontSize -> Scaled[.04]], {.6, .1}], 
   Text[Style["Area 2", FontSize -> Scaled[.04]], {.7, .5}], 
   Text[Style["Area 3", FontSize -> Scaled[.04]], {-.5, .2}], 
   Text[Style["Area 4", FontSize -> Scaled[.04]], {.15, -.6}]};

Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-1, 1}}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, Epilog -> {Circle[], labels}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The disk slices can have different centers and radii:

```
{p1, p2, p3, p4} = meshedParametricPlot @@@ 
       {{{-.25, .1}, {1, 1}, {3 π/4, π}, {# - #2 &, # + #2 &}, 20}, 
       {{0, 0}, {2, 2}, {π/8, 3 π/12}, {#3 &}, 15}, 
       {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, π/8}, {#4 &}, 20}, 
       {{-.25, 0}, {2, 2}, {3 π/2, 3.3 π/2}, {#2 &}, 20}};

Show[p1, p2, p3, p4, PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
    Epilog -> {Circle[], PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}], Circle[{0, 0}, 2], labels}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**2. Using `Graphics` with `Texture`**

First, a function to create texture patterns using `ParametricPlot` and combinations of `Mesh*` options:

```
ClearAll[hatchF]
hatchF[mf_List: {# &, #2 &}, mesh_List: {50, 50}, style_: GrayLevel[.5], 
  opts : OptionsPattern[]] := ParametricPlot[{x, y}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  Mesh -> mesh, MeshFunctions -> mf, MeshStyle -> style, BoundaryStyle -> None, 
  opts, Frame -> False, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0, Axes -> False]
```

Examples:

```
t0 = hatchF[{Sin[10 #2 ] + Cos[5 # ] &, (Sin[10 # ] + Cos[10 #2])  &}, {5, 5}, 
 Directive[ Thick, White], 
 MeshShading -> Dynamic@{{GrayLevel@RandomReal[{.7, .8}], White}, 
   {Hue@RandomReal[], Hue@RandomReal[]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
{t1, t2, t3, t4} = hatchF[#, {#2}, White, 
     MeshShading -> Dynamic@{GrayLevel@RandomReal[{.7, .8}], White}] & @@@ 
 {{{ # - #2 &}, 20}, {{ Norm[{#, #2}] &}, 40}, {{ # &}, 10}, {{#2 &}, 20}};
t5 = hatchF[{# - #2 &, #2 + # &}, {20}, Gray, PlotStyle -> None];
t6 = hatchF[{ Norm[{#, #2}] &}, {40}, Gray, PlotStyle -> None];
t7 = hatchF[{# &, #2 &}, {20}, Gray, PlotStyle -> None];
t8 = hatchF[{ # &}, {30}, Gray, PlotStyle -> None];
t9 = hatchF[{ #2 &}, {30}, Gray, PlotStyle -> None];
Row[{t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

We can use `Texture` for styling `Polygon`s directly:

```
SeedRandom[9]
coords = RandomInteger[10, {10, 2}];
Graphics[{EdgeForm[Black], Texture[t0], 
  Polygon[coords, VertexTextureCoordinates -> Rescale[coords]]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

For disk primitives we need to transform `Disk`s to polygons and then texture them:

```
ClearAll[diskToCoords, texturedPolygon]
diskToCoords[n_] := Module[{angles = Sort@N@#3}, 
    Prepend[Table[#2 {Cos[i], Sin[i]} + #, {i, angles[[1]], angles[[2]], 
    (Subtract @@ Reverse[angles])/n}], #]] &;

texturedPolygon[t_, n_] := Module[{coords = diskToCoords[n] @@ #}, 
    {Texture[t], Polygon[coords, VertexTextureCoordinates -> Rescale[coords]]}] &
```

Examples:

```
disk1 = Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {π, 3 π/4}];
disk2 = Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {π/8, 3 π/12}];
disk3 = Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, π/8}];
disk4 = Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {3 π/2, 3.3 π/2}];

Graphics[{texturedPolygon[t1, 40]@disk1, 
  texturedPolygon[t2, 40]@disk2, texturedPolygon[t3, 40]@disk3, 
  texturedPolygon[t4, 40]@disk4, Black, Circle[], labels}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Graphics[{texturedPolygon[t5, 40]@disk1, 
  texturedPolygon[t6, 40]@disk2, texturedPolygon[t7, 40]@disk3, 
  texturedPolygon[t9, 40]@disk4, Black, Circle[], labels}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Again, disk slices can have different origins and radii:

```
disks = {Disk[{-.25, .25}, {1, 1}, {π, 3 π/4}], 
         Disk[{0, 0}, {2, 2}, {π/8, 3 π/12}], 
         Disk[{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, π/8}], 
         Disk[{-.25, 0}, {2.5, 2.5}, {3 π/2, 3.3 π/2}]};

Graphics[{Circle[], Circle[{0, 0}, 2], 
   texturedPolygon[#, 40][#2] & @@@ Transpose[{{t5, t2, t1, t0}, disks}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**3. Using `ParametricPlot`s with `Texture` as `PlotStyle`**

```
texturedParametricPlot = ParametricPlot[#2 {r Cos[t] , r Sin[t]} + #, 
    {t, #3[[1]], #3[[2]]}, {r, 0, 1}, 
    Mesh -> None, PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[1], Texture[#4]], 
    BoundaryStyle -> GrayLevel[.8], PlotPoints -> 200, 
    TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#, #2} &)] &;

 {p1b, p2b, p3b, p4b} = texturedParametricPlot @@@ 
     {{{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {3 π/4, π},  t5},
     {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {π/8, 3 π/12},  t6}, 
     {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, π/8}, t8}, 
     {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {3 π/2, 3.3 π/2}, t9}};

Show[p1b, p2b, p3b, p4b, PlotRange -> {-1, 1}, AspectRatio -> 1, 
 Frame -> False, Axes -> False, Epilog -> {Circle[], labels}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The disk slices may have different origins and radii:

```
{p1c, p2c, p3c, p4c} =  texturedParametricPlot @@@ 
   {{{-.25, .25}, {1, 1}, {3 π/4, π}, t5}, 
    {{0, 0}, {2, 2}, {π/8, 3 π/12}, t6}, 
    {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, π/8}, t8}, 
    {{-.25, 0}, {2, 2}, {3 π/2, 3.3 π/2}, t9}};

Show[p1c, p2c, p3c, p4c, PlotRange -> {{-2.5, 2.5}, {-2.5, 2.5}}, 
    AspectRatio -> 1, Frame -> False, Axes -> False, 
    Epilog -> {Circle[], Circle[{0, 0}, 2], PointSize[Large], Point[{0, 0}]}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**4. Using `PieChart` with `Texture` and custom `ChartElementFunction`**

```
ClearAll[ceF1]
ceF1[{{t0_, t1_}, {r0_, r1_}}, _, meta___List] := 
  Module[{txtr = If[meta === {}, White, Texture[meta[[1]]]]}, 
   ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, t0, t1}, {r, r0, r1}, 
     Mesh -> None, BoundaryStyle -> Gray, PlotStyle -> txtr, 
     TextureCoordinateFunction -> ({#, #2} &)][[1]]];

 piechartdata = -Subtract @@@ 
    Partition[Sort[N@{0, π, 3 π/4, π/8, 3 π/12, 3 π/2, 3.3 π/2, 2 π}], 2, 1];

PieChart[{Labeled[piechartdata[[1]], labels[[1, 1]]] -> t1, 
  Labeled[piechartdata[[2]], labels[[2, 1]], "RadialCallout"] -> t2, 
  piechartdata[[3]], Labeled[piechartdata[[4]], labels[[3, 1]]] -> t3,
   piechartdata[[5]], Labeled[piechartdata[[6]], labels[[4, 1]]] -> t4, 
  piechartdata[[7]]}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> ceF1, SectorOrigin -> {{0}, .5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can  use the same `ChartElementFunction` with `SectorChart` to have different radii for different pie slices:

```
SectorChart[{Labeled[{piechartdata[[1]], 1}, labels[[1, 1]], RadialCallout"] -> t1, 
  Labeled[{piechartdata[[2]], 2}, labels[[2, 1]], "RadialCallout"] -> t2, 
  {piechartdata[[3]], 0}, 
  Labeled[{piechartdata[[4]], 3}, labels[[3, 1]]] -> t3, 
  {piechartdata[[5]], 0}, 
  Labeled[{piechartdata[[6]], 3}, labels[[4, 1]]] -> t4, 
  {piechartdata[[7]], 0}}, ChartElementFunction -> ceF1, 
 SectorOrigin -> {{0}, .5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**5. Using `PieChart` with `Mesh` lines and custom `ChartElementFunction`**

The following custom function creates pie slices with mesh lines based on parameters that can be passed as meta information associated with each data point:

```
ClearAll[ceF2]
ceF2[{{t0_, t1_}, {r0_, r1_}}, _, meta___List] := 
  Module[{mf = If[meta === {}, {}, meta[[1, 1]]], mesh = If[meta === {}, {}, meta[[1, 2]]]}, 
   Dynamic@ParametricPlot[{r Cos[t], r Sin[t]}, {t, t0, t1}, {r, r0,  r1}, 
  MeshFunctions -> mf, Mesh -> mesh, MeshStyle -> White, 
      BoundaryStyle -> Gray, 
      PlotStyle -> Directive[Opacity[.9], CurrentValue["Color"]]][[1]]];
```

Examples:

```
PieChart[{Labeled[piechartdata[[1]], labels[[1, 1]], 
    "RadialCallout"] -> {{#1 &, #1 - #2 &}, {5, 5}}, 
  Labeled[piechartdata[[2]], labels[[2, 1]]] -> {{#1 - 2 #2 &}, {10}},
  Style[piechartdata[[3]], White], 
  Labeled[piechartdata[[4]], labels[[3, 1]]] -> {{#4 &}, {10}}, 
  Style[piechartdata[[5]], White], 
  Labeled[piechartdata[[6]], labels[[4, 1]], "RadialCallout"] -> {{#3 &}, {5}}, 
  Style[piechartdata[[7]], White]}, 
  ChartElementFunction -> ceF2, SectorOrigin -> {{0}, 1}, ChartStyle -> "Pastel" , 
  ImagePadding -> 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Using it with `SectorChart` with appropriate input data:

```
SectorChart[{Labeled[{piechartdata[[1]], 1}, labels[[1, 1]], 
    "RadialCallout"] -> {{#1 &, #1 - #2 &}, {5, 5}}, 
  Labeled[{piechartdata[[2]], 3}, labels[[2, 1]]] -> {{#1 - 2 #2 &}, {10}},
  {piechartdata[[3]], 0}, 
  Labeled[{piechartdata[[4]], 2}, labels[[3, 1]]] -> {{#4 &}, {10}}, 
  {piechartdata[[5]], 0}, 
  Labeled[{piechartdata[[6]], 3}, labels[[4, 1]], "RadialCallout"] -> {{#3 &}, {5}}, 
  {piechartdata[[7]], 0}}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> ceF2, SectorOrigin -> {{0}, 1}, 
 ChartStyle -> "Pastel" , PlotRangePadding -> 0]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: thanks, I like these results but, because my graphs are quite a bit more complex, the implementation is a bridge too far for me for now. However, given the sophistication of all this programming, my sense is that you are only a couple of steps away from some function `surfaceTreatment[ graphics primitive, surface treatment choice]` that would make all this easy to handle.

Comment: Your improved code is really impressive, many thanks! The problem is that my `Disk` slices do not all have the same center and diameter. They look more like pizza slices arranged outside the pizza box. Thus your improved code is one millimeter away from being directly applicable. But I feel that you could make your code apply to any graphic primitive, no? The next user will not be using `Disk`s.

Comment: @NicholasG, i updated with examples of how the `Texture` and `ParametricPlot` approaches can handle disk slices with different radii and origins. I think the approach using `PieChart` can also be modified to handle the general case. Regarding "any graphic primitive", `Disk` happens to be difficult case as `Texture` doesn't work with `Disk`. `Polygon` primitives does not require any additional processing before applying `Texture`.

Answer (score 6):

Version 12.1 comes with the functions [`HatchFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HatchFilling.html) and [`PatternFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternFilling.html) which make the task much easier:

```
PieChart[{1, 2, 3}, 
 ChartStyle -> {Directive[GrayLevel[.5], HatchFilling["Diagonal"]], 
   Directive[GrayLevel[0], HatchFilling["Horizontal", 2, 7]], 
   Directive[GrayLevel[.7], HatchFilling["Vertical", 5, 10]]}, 
 SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}, 
 ChartLegends -> {"A", "B", "C"},
 LegendAppearance -> {LegendMarkerSize -> 30}]
```

[image]

```
legend = SwatchLegend[
  {Directive[GrayLevel[.5], PatternFilling["Diamond", ImageScaled[.25]]], 
   Directive[GrayLevel[0], PatternFilling["Checkerboard", ImageScaled[.5]]], 
   Directive[GrayLevel[.7], PatternFilling["Hexagon", ImageScaled[.5]]]},
  {"A", "B", "C"}, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> 30];

PieChart[{1, 2, 3}, 
 ChartStyle -> {Directive[GrayLevel[.5], PatternFilling["Diamond", ImageScaled[.025]]], 
   Directive[GrayLevel[0], PatternFilling["Checkerboard", ImageScaled[.05]]], 
   Directive[GrayLevel[.7], PatternFilling["Hexagon", ImageScaled[.1]]]}, 
 SectorOrigin -> {Automatic, 1}, 
 ChartLegends -> legend]
```

[image]

Comment: This is fantastic, I got my copy of 12.1 yesterday and this feature is fantastic. I do have a problem though. I cannot turn it off so the next surface is rendered in a solid grey shade. `PatternFilling[None]` does not do it. Any ideas?

Comment: @NicholasG, interesting. That sounds sounds ike an os-related glitch. It does not arise  on Wolfram Cloud. Perhaps you can post a new question with small example?

Comment: here is what does not work: `Graphics[{PatternFilling["Hexagon", ImageScaled[1/20]],
  Rectangle[],PatternFilling[None],GrayLevel[.8],Disk[{.5, .5}, .5]}]`

Comment: `Opacity` seems to also not work on pattern-filled surfaces. E.g., `Graphics[{Disk[{.5, .5}, .6], Opacity[.1],PatternFilling["Hexagon", ImageScaled[1/20]], Rectangle[]}]`

Comment: My workaround on the former issue is `PatternFilling[{"Checkerboard", GrayLevel[.8], GrayLevel[.8]}]`. On opacity, `PatternFilling[{"Checkerboard",{Opacity[.5],GrayLevel[.8]},...]` causes a fade to black rather than fading to the graphics behind.

Comment: @NicholasG, you can also limit the scope of directives using braces: `Graphics[{{PatternFilling["Hexagon", ImageScaled[1/20]], Rectangle[]},GrayLevel[.8],Disk[{.5, .5}, .5]}] `