# How to fill the region above and below a curve with different colors/patterns?

Tags: plotting, filling

In the curve obtained with following

```
  Plot[{1/(3 x*Sqrt[1 - x^2])}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 GridLines -> {{0.35, 0.94}, {}}]
```

how can one fill the top and bottom with different colors or patterns such that two regions are perfectly visible in a black-n-white printout?

Comment: Look for the option `Filling` !

Comment: It seems to work only for either Top or Bottom, but in my plot, I have a vertical strip which is divided by the curve and I want to highlight the two portions of this strip.

Answer (score 6):

```
Plot[{1/(3 x*Sqrt[1 - x^2]), 1/(3 x*Sqrt[1 - x^2])}, {x, 0, 1}, 
 PlotStyle -> Directive[AbsoluteThickness[2], Opacity[1], Black], 
 PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 GridLines -> {{0.35, 0.94}, {}}, 
 Method -> "GridLinesInFront" -> True, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed], 
 Filling -> {1 -> {Bottom, GrayLevel[.8]}, 2 -> {Top, GrayLevel[.6]}}, 
 RegionFunction -> (.35 <= # <= .94 &)]
```

[image]

To get hatched-filling in older versions we can use `ParametricPlot` with the options [`MeshFunctions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshFunctions.html) + [`Mesh`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Mesh.html) + [`MeshStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MeshStyle.html):

```
Show @ MapThread[
  ParametricPlot[{x, # t + (1 - t)  1/(3 x*Sqrt[1 - x^2])}, 
    {x, 0.35, 0.94}, {t, 0, 1}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
    ImageSize -> Medium, 
    AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio,
    GridLines -> {{0.35, 0.94}, {}},
    BoundaryStyle -> None, 
    PlotStyle -> None, 
    MeshStyle -> Directive[GrayLevel[.3], Opacity[1], 
        AbsoluteThickness[1], CapForm["Butt"]], 
    MeshFunctions -> {#4 &, #2}, 
    Mesh -> {{{0, Directive[Black, Opacity[1], AbsoluteThickness[3], 
         CapForm["Butt"]]}}, #3}] &, 
  {{0, 1}, {# + #2 &, # - #2 &}, {50, 25}}]
```

[image]

```
$Version
```

> ```
> "11.3.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)"
> ```

**See also:**

1. [Generating hatched filling using Region functionality](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/64159/125)
2. [Texture or shading to avoid requiring color printing](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/149113/125)

Answer (score 3):

Since you mentioned that your final product will be in black and white (or perhaps grayscale), I recommend using hatched fillings instead of colors:

```
Plot[
  Evaluate@ConstantArray[1/(3 x*Sqrt[1 - x^2]),2],
  {x, 0.35, .94},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  GridLines -> {{0.35, 0.94}, {}},
  GridLinesStyle -> Directive[Black, Dashed],
  PlotStyle -> Directive[Black, Thickness[0.007]],
  Filling -> {1 -> Top, 2 -> Bottom},
  FillingStyle->{
    Directive[HatchFilling[-Pi/4, 1, 10], Black],
    Directive[HatchFilling[Pi/4, 1, 10], Black]
  }
]
```

[image: plot with two regions highlighted by different hatched filling styles]

Comment: That seems cool! Unfortunately, HatchFilling is not working in my version 11.3.

Comment: @User101 I think it was introduced in version 12.1. Perhaps you could update, or create the plot on the [Wolfram Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/) (which always runs the most updated version).

Answer (score 2):

You have to plot it twice:

```
Show[{
Plot[{1/(3 x*Sqrt[1 - x^2]), 1/(3 x*Sqrt[1 - x^2])}, {x, 0, 1},PlotRange -> {0, 1}, GridLines -> {{0.35, 0.94}, {}}, Filling -> {Top }, FillingStyle -> {Red }],
Plot[{1/(3 x*Sqrt[1 - x^2]), 1/(3 x*Sqrt[1 - x^2])}, {x, 0, 1},PlotRange -> {0, 1}, GridLines -> {{0.35, 0.94}, {}}, Filling -> {Bottom}, FillingStyle -> {Blue },RegionFunction -> Function[x, 0.35 < x < 0.94]]
}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Using [`RegionPlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionPlot.html)

```
RegionPlot[
 {0.35 <= x <= 0.94 && y > 1/(3 x*Sqrt[1 - x^2]),
  0.35 <= x <= 0.94 && y < 1/(3 x*Sqrt[1 - x^2])},
 {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
 PlotStyle -> {
   Lighter[Gray, 0.7],
   Lighter[Gray, 0.9]},
 BoundaryStyle ->
  Directive[AbsoluteThickness[1], Gray],
 PlotPoints -> 75,
 AspectRatio -> 1,
 ImageSize -> 288]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear[plot, pts];
plot = Plot[{1/(3 x*Sqrt[1 - x^2])}, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}];
pts = Cases[plot, Line[a_] :> a, All] // First;
Graphics[{{GrayLevel[.6], Polygon[pts]}, {EdgeForm[Dashed], LightGray,
    Polygon[Join[{{pts[[1, 1]], 0}}, pts, {{pts[[-1, 1]], 0}}]]}}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Axes -> True]
```

[image]