# "Striped bar in a bar chart" problems with available approach

Tags: charts

while searching for solutions making textures in bar charts possible, I found this code posted by the user halmir here:
[Hatched bars and bar-specific background in BarChart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/34035/hatched-bars-and-bar-specific-background-in-barchart)

Unfortunately this doesn't work for low chart heights, which are smaller than the width of the chart. The term  (yt - width) becomes negative and errors appear.

For example:

```
BarChart[{2, -1, .05, -3, 3, 2.5}, BarSpacing -> 2, 
 ChartElementFunction -> barFilled[.65, 3, 35], ChartStyle -> 61, 
 GridLines -> {None, Automatic}]
```

[image]

Is there another solution to change the appearance of barcharts? Already tried the  approach [How to change texture of chart bar?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/21323/how-to-change-texture-of-chart-bar) which uses the texture command and images. For big numbers and stacked bar charts it is noch efficient anymore.

If you know an easy approach for changing barcharts, my computer and I would be very thankful:)

Sorry for the huge text & all the best,
Kilian

Comment: Please add code with a BarChart and data that shows the problem bars, so we don't have to invent a data set etc,

Answer (score 2):

If you are only looking for the stripes then you may use [`HatchFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HatchFilling.html) in the [`ChartStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ChartStyle.html) option.

With

```
dat = {2, -1, .05, -3, 3, 2.5}
```

Then

```
BarChart[dat
 , BarSpacing -> 2
 , ChartStyle -> (Directive[HatchFilling[], ColorData[61, #]] & /@ 
    Range@Length@dat)
 , GridLines -> {None, Automatic}
 ]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

`HatchFilling` added in version 12.1.

For additional fillings see the *Filling in 2D* section of the [`Graphics Directives`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/GraphicsDirectives.html) guide.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:**  A simpler custom chart element function:

```
ClearAll[CEF]
CEF[cedf_ : {"Rectangle"}, op_ : .5] :=   
   {Opacity[op], EdgeForm[],  
    (ChartElementData @@ cedf)[{#[[1, 1]] + {0, 1},  
        Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BoundingBox"][[2]]}, ##2], 
    Opacity[1], EdgeForm[Gray], HatchFilling[45 Degree, 3, 10], 
    ChartElementData["Rectangle"][##]} &;
```

***Examples:***

```
dat = {2, -1, .05, -3, 3, 2.5};

BarChart[dat, 
 ImageSize -> 600, 
 GridLines -> {None, Automatic}, 
 ChartStyle -> 61,  
 BarSpacing -> 2, 
 "BarStartingValue" -> 0,
 Axes -> {False, True}, 
 ChartElementFunction -> CEF[], 
 Epilog -> {GrayLevel[.4], AbsoluteThickness[.2], 
   Line[{{0, 0}, {Length @ data, 0}}]}]
```

[image]

Use `BarSpacing -> 1` and replace `CEF[]` with `CEF[{"FadingRectangle", "GradientOrigin"->Right}]` to get

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
dat = {2, -1, .05, -3, 3, 2.5};
```

An alternative approach using `HatchFilling` as in Edmund's answer and a custom `ChartElementFunction` to add background fillings:

```
backgroundCEF[cedf_ : "Rectangle"] :=    
  ChartElementData[cedf][{#[[1, 1]] + {0, 1},  
     Charting`ChartStyleInformation["BoundingBox"][[2]]}, ##2] &;
```

**Note:** For this chart element function to work properly, we need to add the (undocumented) option `"BarStartingValue" -> 0`  in `BarChart[...]` so that the horizontal coordinates of rectangles are successive integer pairs starting at 0.

**Examples:**

We can use `backgroundCEF` in two ways:

1. Create a separate bar chart with the option `ChartElementFunction -> backgroundCEF[]` and
   combine it with the original bar chart using `Show`, or
2. Use the graphics primitives of the bar chart created with `backgroundCEF[]` as `Prolog` in the original bar chart:

```
Show[BarChart[dat, ImageSize -> 600, 
   ChartStyle -> 61, 
   ChartBaseStyle -> HatchFilling[],  
   BarSpacing -> 2, 
   "BarStartingValue" -> 0, 
   Axes -> {False, True}], 
 BarChart[dat, ImageSize -> 600,
   ChartStyle -> 61, 
   ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Opacity[.2]]], 
   ChartElementFunction -> backgroundCEF[], 
   BarSpacing -> 2, 
   "BarStartingValue" -> 0], 
  Prolog -> {Line[{#, Scaled[{1, 0}, #]} & @ {0, 0}]}]
```

[image]

```
BarChart[dat, ImageSize -> 600, 
  ChartStyle -> 61, 
  ChartBaseStyle -> HatchFilling[],  
  BarSpacing -> 2, 
  "BarStartingValue" -> 0, 
  Axes -> {False, True}, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, Length@dat}, All}, 
  Prolog -> {Line[{#, Scaled[{1, 0}, #]} & @ {0, 0}], 
   First @ BarChart[dat, 
      ChartStyle -> 61, 
      ChartBaseStyle -> Directive[EdgeForm[], FaceForm[Opacity[.2]]], 
      ChartElementFunction -> backgroundCEF[], 
      BarSpacing -> 2, 
      "BarStartingValue" -> 0]}]
```

[image]

Replace `FaceForm[Opacity[.2]]` with `FaceForm[Opacity[.4]]` and use `backgroundCEF["FadingRectangle]` to get

[image]

Use `backgroundCEF["GlassRectangle]` to get

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
dat = {2, -1, .05, -3, 3, 2.5};
```

Yet another approach is to construct background rectangles directly and use them as `Prolog` in `BarChart` (and add the option `"BarStartingValue" -> 0`):

```
colors = ColorData[61] /@ Range[Length @ dat];

xaxis = Line[{#, Scaled[{1, 0}, #]} & @ {0, 0}];

backgroundRectangles = MapThread[
   {Opacity[.2], #, Rectangle[Scaled[{0, -1}, First@#2], Scaled[{0, 1}, Last@#2]]} &, 
  {colors, Partition[Thread[{Range[0, Length @ dat], 0}], 2, 1]}];

BarChart[dat, 
 ImageSize -> 600, 
 ChartStyle -> 61, 
 ChartBaseStyle -> HatchFilling[],  
 BarSpacing -> 2, 
 "BarStartingValue" -> 0, 
 Axes -> {False, True}, 
 PlotRange -> {{0, Length @ dat}, All}, 
 Prolog -> {xaxis, backgroundRectangles}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I modified the code of the former posts like this:

```
barHatched[gap_, h_, seg_, 
color_][{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] := 
Module[{width, line, yt, yb, lend}, {yb, yt} = Sort[{ymin, ymax}];
width = xmax - xmin;

line = Table[{{xmin + i, yb}, {xmin + i, yt}}, {i, 0, width, h/seg}];
line = {Line[line]};

{{Opacity[1], EdgeForm[], 
Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax + gap, ymax}]}, {color, 
CapForm["Butt"], line}, {FaceForm[], 
Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}]}}]


barHatched2[gap_, h_, seg_, 
color_][{{xmin_, xmax_}, {ymin_, ymax_}}, ___] := 
Module[{width, line, line2, yt, yb, lend, lend2}, {yb, yt} = 
Sort[{ymin, ymax}];
width = xmax - xmin;

 line = Table[{{xmin, i}, {xmax, i + width}}, {i, yb, yt - width, 
 h/seg}];
 line2 = 
 Table[{{xmin + i, yb}, {xmax, yb + width - i}}, {i, h/seg, width, 
 h/seg}];

 If[yt > width, lend = line[[-1, 1, 2]]];
 lend2 = line2[[1, 1, 2]];

 line = {If[yt > width, Line[line]],

 Line[Table[{{xmin + i, yb}, {xmax, yb + width - i}}, {i, h/seg, 
   width, h/seg}]],

 If[yt > width, 
 Line[Table[{{xmin, lend + i}, {xmax - (lend + width - yt) - i, 
     yt}}, {i, h/seg, width, h/seg}]],
 Line[
  Table[{{xmin, yb + i}, {xmin + yt - i, yt}}, {i, 0, yt, h/seg}]]]


  };

 {{Opacity[.2], EdgeForm[], 
  Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax + gap, ymax}]}, {CapForm["Butt"], 
  line}, {FaceForm[], Rectangle[{xmin, ymin}, {xmax, ymax}]}}]
```

In cases ymax < width some changes had to be made. 
So it also works for lists with amounts smaller than the width of bars.
Thanks for asking and offering your help!!

Comment: Is this an answer or additional information for the original post?  I ask because it's not clear what the original issue is and therefore it's not clear if the above is an answer or not.  (It's certainly fine and encouraged to answer one's own questions.) It seems that a graphic illustrating the problem would be very helpful.