# How to show an exclusion limit

Tags: plotting, filling

I would like to show an exclusion plot, by having a filling made of parallel tilted lines. 
Any ideas?

Something along these lines

[image]

Comment: Also related: [How can I make hatching filling of plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/13593)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
RegionPlot[x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
MeshFunctions -> {(2 #1 - #2) &, (2 #1 - #2) &}, Mesh -> 100]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Show[RegionPlot[1 < x^2 + y^3 < 2, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
MeshFunctions -> {#1 - #2 &}, Mesh -> 100], 
RegionPlot[0.5 < x^2 + y^2 < 1.5, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
PlotStyle -> {Pink, Opacity[0.5]}, BoundaryStyle -> Dashed]]
```

[image]

Comment: You can do Filling -> Bottom, but I don't know how to show the hashed aspect with filling.

Comment: I want to show this along side a LogPlot, and I'm trying to use Show, but it is showing it in the wrong place. Any suggestions?