# Barchart: Displaying multiple data sets and filling pattern

Tags: charts

Is there a way I can code the following excel bar chart into Mathematica. Is there any guidebook I can follow? I’m struggling displaying multiple data sets into one figure and filling in the bar with different pattern as such:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe26

Comment: Have you checked out the help for `BarChart[]`, there are plenty of examples there that can help you do exactly this?

Comment: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BarChart.html

Comment: I think one can do better than reproducing charts from Excel.  Depending on what aspects you want compared (Series within populations? Populations within series?), you might consider "dot plots".  Posts by @NickCox are very useful:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/149138/how-to-add-a-third-variable-to-a-bar-plot and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/182096/alternative-visualizations-to-3d-bar-chart.

Comment: Can you provide your data and what you have (probably) tried -  so maybe we can help and improve it.

Answer (score 3):

If you have version 12.1, you can use [`PatternFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PatternFilling.html) and [`HatchFilling`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HatchFilling.html) in  `ChartStyle` option setting:

```
SeedRandom[777]
data = RandomReal[10, {5, 3}];

BarChart[data, 
 ChartStyle -> {Directive[Red, HatchFilling[45 Degree, 3, 5]], 
   PatternFilling[{"DiamondBox", Green}, ImageScaled[1/30]], 
   Directive[Blue, HatchFilling[135 Degree, 3, 5]]}, 
 ChartLegends -> {"A", "B", "C"}, 
 LegendAppearance -> {"LegendMarkerSize" -> 30}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**Note:** See also [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216571/125) and [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/216569/125) by Sjoerd C.de Vries