# How to export VECTORIZE image in PDF format as output of ListLinePlot?

Tags: export, pdf-format

It seems that `ListLinePlot` is not generating VECTORIZE PDF file when using Export command.

1. I use the command : `Export["File1.pdf",File1]`
2. I also Right-Click then "Save Graphic As..." File2.pdf

The two files (grouped) are added for clarity. There are differences in the following :

- File size
- Image quality : points gets blurred at high resolution
- Gray **Rectangle** corner points are deformed
- Orange **Polygon** is moving out of the frame in file obtained via (1) approach.

Any solution to this will be helpful.

The complete code is :

```
test = ListLinePlot[iData,
  Mesh -> All, MeshStyle -> Directive[PointSize[0.006]],
  PlotRange -> {{1, 14}, {0, 2.8}},
  FrameLabel -> {"R (km)", 
    "M (\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(M\), \(\[CircleDot]\)]\))"},
  Epilog -> {
    {Black, PointSize[Large], Point[{10.97, 1.97}]},
    {Black, Dashed, 
     Line[{{10.97, 1.97}, {10.97, 1.97}, {0, 1.97}, {10.97, 1.97}}]},
    Text[Rotate[Style["Causality", 15, Black], 48 Degree], {6, 2.3}],
    Text[Rotate[Style["P > \[Infinity]", 15, Black], 
      56 Degree], {4.85, 2.3}],
    Text[Rotate[Style["GR Limit", 15, Black], 0 Degree], {2.6, 2.3}]},
  Prolog -> {Text[Style["PSRJ1614-2230", 16, Black], {10.2, 2.3}],
    {EdgeForm[Thin], RGBColor[1.00, 0.90, 0.80], 
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {10.97, 10.97/2.9}, {0, 10.97/2.9}}]},
    {EdgeForm[Thin], RGBColor[1.00, 0.78, 0.55], 
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {10.97, 4*10.97/9.0}, {0, 4*10.97/9.0}}]},
    {EdgeForm[Thin], RGBColor[1.00, 0.67, 0.33], 
     Polygon[{{0, 0}, {10.97, 10.97/2.0}, {0, 10.97/2.0}}]},
    {EdgeForm[{Thick, GrayLevel[0.6]}], 
     HatchFilling[45 Degree, 0.5, 3], GrayLevel[0.8], 
     Rectangle[{8.3, 1.97 - 0.04}, {12, 1.97 + 0.04}]}}]
```

Dataset is available @ [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PsFasFoA7DqKh5NfIZ7ATx5X7MjzuBeH/view?usp=sharing)

Thanks & Regards,

[image]

Comment: What is your question? Please be clear and to the point.

Comment: Where are files?

Comment: Updated, Any idea about getting VECTOR output from the ListLinePlot ???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

HatchFilling* is implemented as a pixel shader. If pixel shaders are involved, the output will always be a raster.  There might be other reasons, but that is the one that jumped out while reading your code.

* This applies to all of the Filling and Shading directives, VertexColors, and Texture.

Comment: Thanks, @ihojnicki : Any other way I can implement vector shading inside some graphic objects ?

Comment: @KumarGauravSagar There are some non-HatchFilling solutions [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64159/generating-hatched-filling-using-region-functionality) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64185/hatched-filling-for-listlineplot)

Comment: @KumarGauravSagar Also note that the gradient legend shown in the images probably uses a pixel shader, too.

Comment: Thanks Michael E2 for the links...but these solution are too bulky. The problem, I finally checked after @ihojnicki answer and I traced it down to the implementation of HatchFilling only.