# How to change the texture of the graphical objects?

Tags: graphics

I would like to make a number of 2D figures with Graphics[] command, e.g. Disk[], Rectangle[] etc. It is easy to change the colour and opacity, but I would like to have the internal area shaded with lines that could be horizontal, vertical, diagonal, dashed, dotted, with or without  boundaries...

Is there an automatic option to specify this, or I would have to do it manually?

Comment: There is no option to do this, but you can use [Texture](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Texture.html?q=Texture).

Comment: Related or duplicates: [31221](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/31221/how-do-i-plot-a-histogram-with-hatched-shading), [3723](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3723/filling-a-polygon-with-a-pattern-of-insets), and [13593](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13593/how-can-i-make-hatching-filling-of-plot).