# Removing Axes values in DiscretePlot3D

Tags: plotting, ticks

I have a discrete 3D plot from which I want to remove the axes labels and values. To demonstrate what I need, lets consider an example from the `Mathematica` Documentation:

```
DiscretePlot3D[{PDF[MultivariatePoissonDistribution[3, {1, 1}], {t, u}], PDF[MultivariatePoissonDistribution[5, {2, 2}], {t, u}]}, {t, 0, 10}, {u, 0, 10}, ExtentSize -> Full],
```

i.e. see this [link](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot3D.html). This generates the following graph:

[image: A Discrete 3D plot]

I would like to completely remove the values from the image. The reason for this is since I would like to generate the numbers in `Tikz` for a LaTeX typeset. I am aware of the `MateX` library that exists for
Mathematica. I have tried to use `ImagePadding->1` but this has no effect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make the tick labels [transparent and vanishingly small](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2075/9490)

```
DiscretePlot3D[{PDF[
   MultivariatePoissonDistribution[3, {1, 1}], {t, u}], 
  PDF[MultivariatePoissonDistribution[5, {2, 2}], {t, u}]}, {t, 0, 
  10}, {u, 0, 10}, ExtentSize -> Full,
  TicksStyle -> Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0]]
```

[image]

Comment: ...or `LabelStyle -> Transparent`, that is.

Comment: This certainly works, but for completeness is there are way to completely remove the axes values since the image can then be a bit larger. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Sid, sure, see the edit