# FrameTicks setting for "tick marks on all sides, but labels only on right and top"

Tags: plotting, graphics, ticks

**Short version:** Is there a value for the `FrameTicks` option that retains the default tick marks on all sides, and puts tick labels only on the right and top sides?

---

I can imagine all manner of cleverness with `FontOpacity`, `FontSize`, `ImagePadding`, etc. ([for example](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/2075/2464)) to achieve the desired *appearance* in the example use case below, but, for a number of reasons, in this post I would like to focus on the question as it is worded (under **Question** heading).

---

The example below shows what frameticks look like by default.

```
Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> Small, Frame -> True]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

In other words, the default specification for frame ticks can be described in English as:

> (default spec)
>
> 1. Tick *marks* are to be placed on all sides;
> 2. Tick *labels* are to be placed on the left and bottom sides only.

Now, suppose one wants the ticks done according to a small variation of this default spec, one that retains part 1 of the default spec, but changes part 2.  For example:

> (custom spec)
>
> 1. Tick *marks* are to be placed on all sides;
> 2. Tick *labels* are to be placed on the right and top sides only.

---

One approach to achieve this result, of course, is to provide full-blown, **explicit** tick specifications of the form

`{{x1, label1, len1, style1}, …}`

...as the values of *left*, *right*, *bottom*, *top* in

`FrameTicks -> {{left, right}, {bottom, top}}`

This approach is a pain in the butt, of course, but worse still, it does not come close to matching the generality and maintainability of the default<sup>1</sup>.

---

The only other *documented* possibility is to use some combination of the symbolic settings `None`, `Automatic`, `True`, and/or `All`.

In search for the "magic combination", I tried the expression

```
Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> Small, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{a, b}, {a, b}}]
```

for all possible combinations of values for `a` and `b`.  (I made a chart of the results for future reference; I've appended it at the end of this post.)  The only one that came close to implementing the desired spec was `a = None, b = All`:

```
Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> Small, Frame -> True,
         FrameTicks -> {{None, All}, {None, All}}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

This result comes up short because it does not satisfy part 1 of the desired specification.

Bottom line, I have not managed to find a *documented* setting for `FrameTicks` that implements the desired spec.

---

**Question**

My main question is:

**In addition to the one consisting of explicit tick specifications, is there some other (most likely undocumented) value *for the* `FrameTicks` *option* that implements the custom spec above?**

---

Secondarily, I'm also curious to know if there is some documentation that explains why the custom spec above needs to be made so difficult to implement robustly.

---

P.S. For future reference, in the chart below, the label next to each side gives its `FrameTick`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Notes**

1. In all cases, *left* and *bottom* have the same setting, and likewise for the settings for *right* and *top*.
2. Along each row, the settings for *left* and *bottom* are constant.  Along each column, the settings for *right* and *top* are constant.
3. The effect of the `True` setting (ironically enough) is not universally consistent; it depends on which side it is applied to.  On the *left* and *bottom*, the effect is "ticks and labels"; on the *right* and *top*, it is "ticks only; no labels".  (The same could be said of the `Automatic` setting, but this is reasonable under the interpretation of `Automatic` as "default".)

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For example, I don't know how I could use this approach in a function that takes some data as input and produces a framed plot that meets the custom tick specification.</sup>

Comment: I moved your distinguishing statement to the top of the is question as to one degree or another the first three answers posted, mine being one of them, all seem to have ignored it.  I deleted my answer which was just an example of `ImagePadding`.

Comment: @corey979: *Mathematica* is huge, and its documentation is often incomplete.  Knowing that something is not implemented is, in itself, useful information.  It saves people a futile search.

Answer (score 12):

Following the strict requirements of your question the nearest solution I can offer is this.

I use the internal tick generating function to behave as `All` does, but remove the labels.

*Edit*: I found that what I wrote is already implemented in `` Charting`ScaledFrameTicks ``.

```
magic = Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{# &, # &}];

Graphics[{}
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameTicks -> {{magic, All}, {magic, All}}
]
```

[image]

Comment: One weird thing with `Charting\`ScaledFrameTicks` is that many of the ticks disappear, as you can see on the bottom edge of your example. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 8):

[`FrameTicks`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicks.html) together with [`FrameTicksStyle`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FrameTicksStyle.html) do it (as far as I know it's **not possible** with `FrameTicks` only:

```
Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> Small, Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> All, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> {{Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0], Automatic},
                     {Directive[FontOpacity -> 0, FontSize -> 0], Automatic}}]
```

[image]

(obtained with `$Version`: `"10.4.1 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (April 11, 2016)"`).

---

As pointed out by Szabolcs, in v10.0 (and later) on OSX this does not crop the image, but leaves large borders on the bottom and left. The solution is to change `FontSize -> 0` to `FontSize -> 0.1`.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried to rule out this solution in my PS, but I guess I was not explicit enough.

Comment: `FrameTicks` are ticks + labels; ruling out one rules out the other. I very recently was searching for a solution to a similar issue and came up with altering the font options of `FrameTicks` via `FrameTicksStyle`. I highly doubt there's a _simpler_ method to achieve this goal (although I would like to find out I'm mistaken).

Comment: This will not remove the labels: it will leave enough padding for them.  But it's good as a quick and dirty solution.

Comment: @Szabolcs Technically it does not _remove_ the labels, but makes them infinitesimally small, cropping the image as much as (by default) possible: https://imgur.com/a/IB4eE

Comment: @Szabolcs Why the edit?

Comment: @corey979 For some reason it doesn't work on my machine, M11.1 on OS X.  Before I saw your comment, I tried it.  I copied your code, evaluated it, exported the result, and inserted it into your post (with a yellow background to make the size of the white image clear).  Despite the `FontSize -> 0`, I still see large borders.  Do you not get these on your machine?

Comment: @corey979 The edit was to make the size of the borders clear.  I did not see your comment when I made the edit.  I thought that you uploaded a screenshot instead of an actual exported figure, and that you unknowingly cropped the borders. Now I realize that that is not the case.  But let's figure out why we get different things. What's your version and OS?

Comment: @Szabolcs No, see my original image and https://imgur.com/a/IB4eE. But I'm on v10.4.1 and that's the output I get.

Comment: What OS are you using?  This is what I get in 10.4.1: http://i.stack.imgur.com/EAwQY.png  Can you spot the problem?

Comment: Maybe it's OS dependent; see edit.

Comment: It seems that on my computer, `FontSize -> 0` does not work in any version.  However, `FontSize -> 0.1` does work, and produces the result you showed.  Maybe mention this in your post.  I'm on OS X.

Comment: @cory979 "`FrameTicks` are ticks + labels": that depends on which side one refers to.

Comment: Sorry, and thanks for the edit!  +1, this weirdness with a zero font size can be very confusing and is good to point out.

Comment: corey979, I just got to the part of the question *I can imagine all manner of cleverness with FontOpacity, FontSize, ImagePadding* which disqualified my hack and well as your answer, so I deleted mine and put a -1 on yours.  Sorry.  By the way you were entirely right about my hack not working so well.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I don't agree with the downvote. If anyone shows how to do it with `FrameTicks` only, I will also remove my answer. As far as I understand, it's not possible to achieve the result without additional options (SciDraw is not only an options, but whole package, so it also does not fit in the requirements). So maybe this question should be closed as one that asks for a feature that is not possible?

Comment: @corey979 I also think it is not possible as written.  However that doesn't make your post an answer to the question.  kjo was already aware of this method even though he didn't make that prominently clear in his original Question.

Comment: @corey979 Whether or not this should be closed is a separate issue.  I don't know if there exist clear guidelines for that.  I have also asked for features that do not exist [(346)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/346/121), and one of the more popular questions on this site *was* mostly of that type [(1953)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1953/121).  However in other cases we have closed questions where the OP seems to simply want *Mathematica* to work like another product and isn't open to alternatives, etc.

Comment: I appreciate this discussion, but isn't the need for it kind of ridiculous in the first place? This isn't a particularly odd or unique thing to ask for...

Answer (score 6):

With `CustomTicks` (part of [SciDraw](http://scidraw.nd.edu/), but also usable independently) it's easy to truly remove the tick labels:

```
Needs["CustomTicks`"]
```

```
(* Optional: adjust tick style. Done here so one can better see the ticks *)

linestyle = {AbsoluteThickness[1], Black};

SetOptions[LinTicks, MajorTickLength -> {0.04, 0}, 
  MinorTickLength -> {0.015, 0}, MajorTickStyle -> linestyle, 
  MinorTickStyle -> linestyle];
```

```
(* actual plot *)
Graphics[{}, ImageSize -> Small, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {StripTickLabels[LinTicks], StripTickLabels[LinTicks], 
   LinTicks, LinTicks}]
```

[image]