# Missing frame ticks after removing tick labels

Tags: plotting, bugs, ticks

In [this solution](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/140971/5784) by @Mr.Wizard, some of the ticks along the bottom edge of the frame are clearly missing. This happens every time I use Charting`ScaledFrameTicks. Is there a fix?

For reference, here is the code and the output:

```
magic = Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{# &, # &}];

Graphics[{}
 , Frame -> True
 , FrameTicks -> {{magic, All}, {magic, All}}
]
```

[image: Output]

Comment: Use ``Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}]`` instead.

Comment: @CarlWoll thanks, that fixed the missing ticks. But now I'm seeing another weird behavior. At least in the plot I'm currently making, it decided to draw major ticks at a different frequency on the edges that use `Charting` (bottom and right in my picture). Every fifth tick instead of everything fourth. https://imgur.com/bjZ84bU

Comment: Can you provide an example that shows the issue?

Comment: @CarlWoll took me some time to find a minimal example, but it suffices to just add `PlotRange -> {{-Pi/4, Pi/4}, {-Pi/4, Pi/4}}` to your example to get this https://imgur.com/a/4j9AGXa

Comment: That's because the All/Automatic ticks are generated using different code from ``Charting`ScaledFrameTicks``. One possibility is to use: ``Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Identity, Identity}][-Pi/4, Pi/4, {8, 4}]`` instead. Another possibiity is to use ``Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}]`` instead of All.

Comment: @CarlWoll Amazing, thank you!